# Get <select> value in $(this) row

Tags: php, jquery, select, row

I have a table consisting of elements like this

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <button id="button"></button>   
</tr>
```

How can i get all values of current row including selected option when press button by using jquery?
I want to get: 1 'a'('a' option selected for example) 3

Comment: Does it have to be jQuery? JavaScript makes it very easy already. Also, why are `<select>` and `<button>` between `<td>`s and `<tr>`s?

Comment: Dont want to use part jquery, part js in one code, but if you have a solution in js it would be nice to hear it to know the way where to dig.(misstags fixed)

Comment: ***sigh*** You're using JavaScript **either way**. It's just in one case, you're using jQuery's API (which uses the DOM under the covers). In the other case, you're using the DOM directly. The *language* doesn't change.

Comment: *"How can i get all values of current row"* What do you mean by "values"? It would help if you said, specifically, what information you want from the quoted row.

Comment: I mean, if you want it in jQuery, sure. It's just that it's not necessary because you can do it straight up with JavaScript, no need to use jQuery. @T.J.Crowder and I already know that, it's just that I prefer to keep it short instead of explaining the entire thing about jQuery vs JavaScript.

Comment: I want to get: 1 'a'('a' option selected for example) 3

Comment: @Zeke: Great, keep it short: "Does it have to be jQuery? The DOM makes it very easy already." Perhaps [DOM](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) could even be a link.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why are you so mad about me misusing the terms if it was perfectly understood? Communication does not require perfection unless it is some kind of legal document. I understand that it might be wrong _technically_, but there's no need to make a fuss about it. As long as the sender and recipient understand the same thing, it is completely valid.

Comment: @Zeke: I'm not mad. :-) Mis-identifying the technology you're using means you won't be effective searching for solutions using that technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "values" you mean the 1 and the 3 in the other two cells, you'd use `closest` to find the row, then use `find` or `children` to access the `td`s in it. Here's one way you might do it:

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  // Get the row
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  // Get the cells and their contents:
  row.children("td").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Ignore the one with the button
    if (!$this.find("button").length) {
      // Does this one have the select?
      var select = $this.find("select");
      if (select.length) {
        // Yes, use that
        console.log(select.val());
      } else {
        // No, grab text
        console.log($(this).text());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><select>
      <option>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <button id="button">I'm a button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But [refer to the API](http://api.jquery.com), there are lots of other ways you might access those `td`s.

---

Note that I wrapped the `button` in a `td`. Your original markup is invalid, you can't have a `button` as a direct child of a `tr`.

Also note that if you have more than one `tr`, you can't use `id="button"` on all of them (probably better to use a class), but I'm guessing from the ID that that's just a placeholder you put in for the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is why I'm here.

Comment: Although there are many ways to access the `td`s, as mentioned in the answer, this is definitely the best way in my opinion because of the button placement. The final note is very useful, props for that.